# Luminosity and absolute magnitude relationship

Tags: astronomy, sun, stars, luminosity, white-dwarfs

Context : an exercise gives the temperature, mass, distance and apparent magnitude of Sirius B and asks to calculate its density.

One key step of the calculation is to get the luminosity from the absolute magnitude (with the intent of then using Stefan-Boltzmann law to get the area).

I get this step wrong. With an absolute magnitude of 11.2 (in agreement with Wikipedia's value of 11.18), I use the formula :

$$L = L_S * 10^{ (M_S - M)/2.5 }$$

Where $L_S$ and $M_S$ are the luminosity and absolute magnitude of the Sun, and $L$,$M$ are the luminosity and absolute magnitude of Sirius B.

Using $M_S = 4.83$, I get $L = 0.0028L_S$, which disagrees with Wikipedia's value $L = 0.056L_S$ (and then, of course, I get the density wrong).

Where is my mistake ?

Comment: Absolute magnitude in what spectral band?

Comment: @JohnDoty in the V band

Comment: Need to correct to bolometric magnitude.

Comment: @JohnDoty ah yes it works better thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up absolute magnitude in a particular spectral band (in this case, the V band) with the bolometric absolute magnitude over all wavelengths.

It is the latter you need and that is related to luminosity through the equation you have used. You can just about get away with using V band magnitudes *if* the stars being compared are of similar spectral type.

Here however, you are comparing the Sun with the considerably hotter Sirius B. The proportion of its flux in the V band is much smaller than for the Sun. That is why you have derived a much smaller luminosity than the correct (bolometric) value.

The correct path is to use absolute bolometric magnitudes for both stars. This can be achieved by applying temperature-dependent bolometric corrections to the V band magnitudes.

Comment: Ok it makes a lot of sense, thanks